# Joomla migration Fatal error: Call to a member function render() on a non-objec html.php on line 399

Tags: php, database, joomla, migration

I just migrate my joomla 3.1 site from localhost to my web server and I realized that I have this error coming out of nowhere.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function render() on a non-objec in homepages/18/d292073622/htdocs/libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php on line 399
```

I have properly migrated my database and I have change the configuration file to the new settings. I am sharing the same database with another wordpress installation, but they have different dbprefix

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the stack trace? What OS did you migrate from? If this is Windows to Linux, this may be a case sensitivity issue with file names.

Comment: Very strange. What PHP version is the webserver running? Please provide stacktrace

Comment: How did you migrate? Did you use a tool like Akeeba or do it yourself?

Comment: I am using 1and1 hosting, I migrated just copying the database and the files to the server... The php version was at 5.2 and it was nor working so I change it to 5.4 and I am getting this error now

Comment: 1 and 1 hosting said that it could be a memory problem, I will try to install joomla from scratch and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely the Cache or the Global Configuration settings stored in the database.... log into the administrator and clear all cache (including template cache) and then go through the global configuration and save those settings again.  Should fix it all.  Just had the exact same issue come up on my site.